# Evaluate the integral $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac { dx} { a+ \sin^2x } , |a| >1 ?$

Tags: complex-analysis

Evaluate the integral  by the  method of  residue

$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac { dx} { a+ \sin^2x } , |a| >1$

My attempt : there is  one formula  $\sin^2( x)  = \frac{1- \cos2(x)}{2}$ after  putting this  formula  i got $$2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac { dx} { (2a +1) - \cos2x } \tag 1$$

There is one  formula  in complex integration that is   $\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac { dx} { a+ \cos x } = \frac{ \pi}{\sqrt {a^2-1}} \tag 2$

Here How  can we collaborate  $(1)$ and $(2)$,?

actually $(1)$  is  not in the form  $\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac { dx} { a+ \cos x }$ so  im getting  confused  due  to negative sign before $\cos(2x)$

Comment: Let $x = t/2$ then use (2). But if the question says "by the method of residues", this isn't the method.

Comment: But it should be ok to first prove $(2)$ using the residue theorem, and then use it.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool i got $\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac { dt} { (2a +1) - \cos2t } $  Im  confused becoz  it is not match  with $(2)$   due to  negative sign before $\cos (2x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already noted
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{a+\sin^{2}\left(x\right)}dx = 2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\left(2a+1\right)-\cos\left(2x\right)}dx =-\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{\left(-2a-1\right)+\cos\left(x\right)}dx$$
Now, the formula you provide, namely
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{a+\cos\left(x\right)}dx \stackrel{?}{=} \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}$$holds *only* for positive values of $a$. The formula should  in fact be
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{a+\cos\left(x\right)}dx = \begin{cases} \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-1}} & a > 1 \\ \frac{-\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-1}} & a < -1 \end{cases}$$
(I am ignoring the cases where the radical is complex, but we can define a value there too if you desire). I imagine this is the reason you are geting a negative sign showing up; you are assuming $a$ is positive, but then $(-2a - 1)$ is *negative*, and is in fact less than $-1$.

Comment: thanks u @ Brevan Ellefsen     that  mean answer will be   $$-\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{\left(-2a-1\right)+\cos\left(x\right)}dx=- \frac{\pi}{ \sqrt {(-2a -1)^2 -1 }}=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac { dx} { a+ \sin^2x } , |a| >1$$  Is  its correct ?

Comment: @jasmine  Beware of the negative sign in front of the first integral.  For $a>1$, the answer should be positive.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool then  how can we remove negative  sign ?

Comment: Because you get another negative sign.  Read Brevan's last equation again.  (But you don't get another negative sign if $a<-1$.)  So the final answer is $$\frac{\pi\operatorname{sgn}(a)}{2\sqrt{a(a+1)}},$$ which in fact works for $a>0$ or $a<-1$ (not just $|a|>1$).

Comment: thanks  u  got its @WETutorialSchool